# Calculating the minimum vs calculating the maximum

Tags: java, for-loop

I suspect I have made an error when writing my "lowestScore" method (I more or less negated my "largestScore" method because that was consistently returning the correct value (the highest score from the array). but for some reason my lowestScore method either just returns back the first element in the array or some arbitrary number, not even from the array. Any ideas?

```
    public static double highestScore(double[] scores)
    {
      double max = scores[0];
      for (int i=0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] > max) {
          max = scores[i];
        }
      }
      return max;
    }

    public static double lowestScore(double[] scores)  //possible problem some where in
    {                                                  //here?
      double min = scores[0];
      for (int i=0; i > scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] < min) {
          min = scores[i];
        }
      }
      return min;
    }
```

Comment: edited the question to leave only the actual question. Making questions easy to read makes them also easier to answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the pointer, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the problem is in `lowestScore`. You inverted both `<` and `>`, but you should still loop over your entire array. In your code, `i > scores.length` (which is `0 > scores.length` initially) evaluates to `false`, so the loop is not executed and `min` is always equal to `scores[0]`.

Change

```
for (int i=0; i > scores.length; i++)
```

To

```
for (int i=0; i < scores.length; i++)
```

Comment: its these small things that have taken hours to spot. Glad to know after trying to figure it out I can come here and see the correct way and actually learn something. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double lowestScore(double[] scores)  //possible problem some where in
{                                                  //here?
  double min = scores[0];
  for (int i=0; i > scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] < min) {
      min = scores[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
}
```

The line `for (int i=0; i > scores.length; i++) {`. The condition says "continue looping if `i` is greater than `scores.length`". When `i` is now initialized to 0, it is never greater than the array's size. So, the loop ends instantly and the return value is the first element of the array, as set before the loop.

P.S. It's easy to undenstand the mistake, you were just inverting the `<`s and `>`s when changing `highestScore` to `lowestScore`.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This kind of feedback is priceless to a beginner like myself.